# Subsetting using MultiIndex with Time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multi-index, data-munging

I am new to the MultiIndex in pandas but I have a situation where it would be helpful. I have a df with a MultiIndex (ON_SCENE and LAST) structured as so:

```
                              ID                
ON_SCENE            LAST                                                    
2016-05-05 03:58:54 last1    1000            
2016-05-05 17:23:39 last1    1001             
2016-05-05 18:20:50 last1    1002             
2016-05-05 21:30:29 last2    1003           
2016-05-05 22:33:19 last2    1004  
2016-05-05 23:30:23 last3    1005
2016-05-06 00:08:34 last3    1006
2016-05-06 01:33:54 last3    1007
```

I want to subset this data using a date and last name as so:

```
df.loc[j.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),Last_Name]
```

where j is type `datetime.date` and Last_Name  is a `str` with a last name. Unfortunately, I keep getting a KeyError. I have also tried:

```
    df[j.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
    df[Last_Name]
```

But these also give me a KeyErrors. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [103]: x.loc[('2016-05-05', 'last2'), :]
Out[103]:
                             ID
ON_SCENE            LAST
2016-05-05 21:30:29 last2  1003
2016-05-05 22:33:19 last2  1004
```

or using pd.IndexSlice:

```
In [104]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [105]: x.loc[idx['2016-05-05':'2016-05-06', 'last3'], :]
Out[105]:
                             ID
ON_SCENE            LAST
2016-05-05 23:30:23 last3  1005
2016-05-06 00:08:34 last3  1006
2016-05-06 01:33:54 last3  1007
```

[Pandas Documentation with examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the columns. The first one worked for me and makes the most sense (although, for others that find this, I received a `lexsort` error which required me to run `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` before the solution worked).

Comment: @jtam, glad i could help. Yes, Pandas expect lexographically sorted indexes when using slices...